# Tokenizing first and last name as one token

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize

Is is possible to tokenize a text in tokens such that first and last name are combined in one token?
For example if my text is:

```
text = "Barack Obama is the President"
```

Then:

```
text.split()
```

results in:

```
['Barack', 'Obama', 'is', 'the, 'President']
```

how can I recognize the first and last name? So I get only `['Barack Obama', 'is', 'the', 'President']` as tokens.

Is there a way to achieve it in Python?

Comment: whish this helps: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a named entity recognition system. I suggest you do not consider this as part of tokenization.

For python you can use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ner/

Example from the site

> >>> tagger.json_entities("Alice went to the Museum of Natural History.")
>   '{"ORGANIZATION": ["Museum of Natural History"], "PERSON": ["Alice"]}'

Comment: Thanks, it looks like a good tool except I could not get it to work because of this error: `NLTK was unable to find the java file!
Use software specific configuration paramaters or set the JAVAHOME environment variable.`, however I accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regular expression that meets the needs of your question.  It will find individual words beginning with a lowercase character, or match singleton or pairs of capitalized words.

```
import re
re.findall(r"[a-z]\w+|[A-Z]\w+(?: [A-Z]\w+)?",text)
```

outputs

```
['Barack Obama', 'is', 'the', 'President']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is a good start but not quite accurate as if the text is: `Mr Barack Obama is the President`, it will produce: `['Mr Barack', 'Obama', 'is', 'the', 'President']`.

Comment: If you wish to capture longer contiguous phrases of capitalized words, change the pattern to `r"[a-z]\w+|[A-Z]\w+(?: [A-Z]\w+)*"`  But regular expressions do have their limits.  I'd suggest looking into NER (named entity recognition) systems, such as [NLTK](http://nltk.org)