# Consider two consecutive words as one in Word Frequency

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have this sentence:

```
Sentence
    Who the president of Kuala Lumpur is?
```

I am trying to extract all the words (tokenization)

```
low_case = df['Sentence'].str.lower().str.cat(sep=' ')
words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(low_case)
word_dist = nltk.FreqDist(words)

example = pd.DataFrame(word_dist.most_common(1000),
                    columns=['Word', 'Freq'])
```

However, I would like to extract Kuala Lumpur as bi-gram, so I am considering a filter which says "if there are two consecutive words having capital letters, extract them as a unique word.
So if I have this list:

```
    Who the president of Kuala Lumpur is?
```

I would have (using the code above):

```
Word            Freq
who               1
is                1
president         1
of                1
Kuala             1
Lumpur            1 
is                1
```

but I would like to have this:

```
Word            Freq
who               1
is                1
president         1
of                1
Kuala Lumpur      1
is                1
```

I think to find two consecutive capital letters I should apply the following pattern:

```
pattern = r"[A-Z]{2}-\d{3}-[A-Z]{2}"
```

o anche:

```
re.findall('([A-Z][\w-]*(?:\s+[A-Z][\w-]*)+)', df.Sentence.tolist())
```

But I do not know how to include this information in my code above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tokenizing first and last name as one token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23509481/tokenizing-first-and-last-name-as-one-token)

Comment: Hi Bill, this is what I already did. I would need to group by together the two words, after identified as in the expected output. Right now I have the code that works tokenised them once and the re.findall which select the consecutive words with  capital letters. But they are not counted together as one

Answer (score 0):

You could do some pre-processing and separate the bi-grams from the rest of the sentence using [re Match Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects). For example:

```
import re

# initialize sentence text
sentence_without_bigrams = 'Who the president of Kuala Lumpur or Other Place is?'
bigrams = []

# loop until there are no remaining bi-grams
while True:
    # find bi-grams
    match = re.search('([A-Z][\w-]*(?:\s+[A-Z][\w-]*)+)', sentence_without_bigrams)
    if match == None:
        break
    else:
        # add bi-gram to list of bi-grams
        bigrams.append(sentence_without_bigrams[match.start():match.end()])
        # remove bigram from sentence
        sentence_without_bigrams = (sentence_without_bigrams[:match.start()-1] + sentence_without_bigrams[match.end():])


print(bigrams)
>> ['Kuala Lumpur', 'Other Place']

print(sentence_without_bigrams)
>> Who the president of or is?
```

However, this solution falls short of your ultimate goal, since a sentence like `'Hello, Mr President Obama'` would not be captured correctly (as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23509481/tokenizing-first-and-last-name-as-one-token)).

Comment: thanks Lisa. Yes, that's right. However I would need to group by and take the count of words for considering only as one word. It was clear to me how to split by considering two consecutive words, but not how to get the count /word frequency